# QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected

Tags: multithreading, qt

In QT(C++),while closing qdialog I am facing this issue & application is crashing.
qdialog->deleteLater();

Comment: Add some details to your question. At this point people can only guess where the problem might be.

Comment: You have to prepare a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem, and edit the question to include it. We can then try to help you out with redesigning your code to make it work. There are various ways of accessing the GUI from other threads, and even doing some GUI work in worker threads, but it's impossible to steer you without understanding your requirements.

Comment: i guess you called a repaint function in a paint event?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't provide any details, the *multithreading* tag is rather telling.

You are misusing the GUI classes by accessing non-thread-safe methods on objects that live in the main thread, such as widgets, from another thread. This won't ever work.